# Recursively sampling a triangle from its vertices?

Tags: matlab, recursion, math

I need to evenly sample a triangle just using its vertices (which I have in cartesian coordinates). I need to do it recursively (or at least in generations, where I can use the new point before calculating the next). One example would be like this:

1. take the 3 parent points (in the first execution the vertices)
2. calculate their midpoint as the child
3. get all new possible combinations of the child with 2 of its parents
4. repeat a set amount of times.

Problem: This does not yield an even distribution, but some (nice) pattern.

Using the distance to the parents as an abort criterion enhances the performance by a bit, but the resolution close to the vertices and the midpoint is really bad.

[image: Result with abort criterion]

The function currently looks like this:

```
function points = distMidPoint(parents, distMax)

child = mean(parents);

if any(vecnorm(parents - child,2,2) <= distMax)
% check if distance to the parents falls below a certain threshold
    points = [];
    return
end

points = child;

for iParents = nchoosek(1:size(parents,1),size(parents,1)-1)'
% concatenate child and any combination of two parents and call function again
    newPoint = distMidPoint([parents(iParents,:); child], distMax);
    points = [points; newPoint];
end
    
end
```

Is there an algorithm I just don't know about that does this or do you have a better idea? As I mentioned it doesn't have to be recursive, it was just my first intuition.

Edit: The algorithm works fine for 2 "vertices" that I connect with a line:

[image]

Comment: What does it mean to "sample" a triangle? And what is the problem with what you did?

Comment: I want to find points that lie in the triangle and they should be evenly distanced. Latter is the problem with my current approach.

Comment: I read "evenly distanced" as they should have the same distance between each other. But that is not what your algorithm does. So care to clarify what you want to do?

Comment: Algorithm recommendations (i.e. research literature recommendations) is off topic in stackoverflow.

Comment: So I edited my entry with a 2nd picture that shows how the algorithm works for 2 points that i connect with a line and that's what I want to do with more points. In general, what I want to do is find an even grid of points inside of the triangle.

This is somewhat a simplification of my real problem, where I find this child, shift it and then use it, but I can't expect for it to work with transformation, if it doesn't without :)

Comment: This part I don’t understand: “I need to do it recursively (or at least in generations, where I can use the new point before calculating the next).” You said generating a grid of points is easy. Why can’t you use each of the points of that grid before you compute the next? Does there need to be some sort of hierarchical process that makes the grid more refined as the algorithm progresses?

Comment: So to be a bit more specific: I have a 2-dimensional surface in the 3-dimensional space that I want to sample, without knowing how it actually looks like. All I know of it are 3 points. Now my idea is the following: I start in the midpoint of my 3 vertices and shoot a ray in normal direction of the plane spanned by my 3 vertices onto the surface until it hits and that is the child I find. Now I repeat this with the child and 2 of the parents. By doing so I adapt to the topology of the surface. The problem my question is about is just a simplified toy problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking to subdivide your triangle into smaller, equally sized triangles.

One reasonable way to do this would be to recursively divide the triangle into four smaller triangles by "chopping off the corners." This is similar to the Sierpinski triangle, but you would subdivide all four subdivisions in each step.

You can construct a list of your triangles with the following algorithm (this is Matlab-like pseudocode, since I no longer have a valid license):

```
% takes the vertices of the triangle and the number of times to subdivide.
function points = subdivide(vertices, depth)

if depth <= 0
    points = [[v1, v2, v3]] % list of triangles
else
    s1 = [v1, midpoint(v1, v2), midpoint(v1, v3)]
    s2 = [v2, midpoint(v2, v3), midpoint(v2, v1)]
    s3 = [v3, midpoint(v3, v1), midpoint(v3, v2)]
    s4 = [midpoint(v1, v2), midpoint(v2, v3), midpoint(v3, v1)]
    points = cat(1,
        subdivide(s1, depth-1),
        subdivide(s2, depth-1),
        subdivide(s3, depth-1),
        subdivide(s4, depth-1)
    )
end

end
```

Note: here, a triangle is a list of three points. The input is a triangle and the number of times to subdivide. The result is a list of triangles. The midpoint should be easy to write.

Note that the number of triangles in the result is 4^depth (grows exponentially), so don't make it too big. I tried implementing this algorithm in Python, and here's the result with `depth=5`:
[image]

Comment: Hey, thank you so much! That's working way better than my approach! Still some holes, but it's something that won't matter that much. I will try it out in my actual problem.

Comment: Still some holes? Could you send an image of what you're seeing? If this did what I meant it to, there shouldn't be any "holes." I'll try out this algorithm in Python...

Comment: I found the problem. There was a typo in the calculation of `s3`. `midpoint(v2, v2)` should have been `midpoint(v3, v2)`. Hopefully that takes care of the holes you were seeing.

Comment: @MKHoffmann it sounds like this answered your question, but if there's anything else to clarify/add/explain I'd be happy to address it. If this fully answered your question, please mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Hi! Sorry I thought I already did. Thank you again for your help, I really appreciate it :)